# Create priority_queue using struct and map

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I have struct:

```
struct Node {
    unsigned char symbol;
    unsigned int freq;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(unsigned char _byte, int _freq)
        : symbol(_byte), freq(_freq), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {};
};
```

and already created such `unordered_map`:

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned char, uint> freqs ={{'a',12}, {'b',122}};
```

What I want to do - is to create `priority_queue` the next way:

1. Create new Node for every pair from `freqs`
2. Create `priority_queue` from all of this `Node`s.

What I tried so far:
create vector from map and try to create priority_queue:

```
bool nodeCompare(const Node* first, const Node* second){
    return first->freq > second->freq;
}

typedef std::priority_queue<Node*,
                            std::vector<Node*>,
                            nodeCompare()> my_queue;

std::vector<Node*> node_vect;
std::unordered_map<byte, uint>::iterator it;
for (it = freqs.begin(); it != freqs.end(); ++it)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node(it->first, it->second);
    node_vect.push_back(new_node);
}
my_queue(node_vect.begin(), node_vect.end(), nodeCompare);
```

But this doesn't work: error in `typedef` construction:

> function "nodeCompare" is not a type name

**Additional question:**
if I create my vector in this way, maybe there is some method to push Nodes into my_queue without creating additional vector?

```
my_queue q;
std::vector<Node*> node_vect;
std::unordered_map<byte, uint>::iterator it;
for (it = freqs.begin(); it != freqs.end(); ++it)
{
    Node* new_node = new Node(it->first, it->second);
    node_vect.push_back(new_node);
    //q.push(new_node); this doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

priority_queue template parameter doesn't expect a function but instead an object Type

```
template <class T, class Container = vector<T>,
  class Compare = less<typename Container::value_type> > class priority_queue;
```

so just wrap that function into a struct/class (Functor) and that should work.

```
struct Comparator
{
  bool operator()(const Node* first, const Node* second) const {
    return first->freq > second->freq;
  }
};

typedef std::priority_queue<Node*,
                            std::vector<Node*>,
                            Comparator> my_queue;
```

If you want the Comparator inside the Node struct just make an inner struct

```
struct Node {
    unsigned char symbol;
    unsigned int freq;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;

    Node(unsigned char _byte, int _freq)
        : symbol(_byte), freq(_freq), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {};

    struct Comparator
    {
      bool operator()(const Node* first, const Node* second) const {
        return first->freq > second->freq;
      }
    };
};

typedef std::priority_queue<Node*,
                            std::vector<Node*>,
                            Node::Comparator> my_queue;

my_queue queue(node_vect.begin(), node_vect.end());
```

Comment: can I add `Comparator` into my `Node` struct? and use it in typedef? Or I need to create new one?

Comment: Yeah there is no problem with that

Comment: can you show the example please? I can't figure out how to add - tried as struct method, but still doesn't work :(

Comment: Awesome! It works! I already voted your answer!
But I have one more question - don't know is it ok to ask here again... Look at my addition to the question please.

Comment: Ohh, looks like this was typo :)